# Run py file with variable name in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using %run to run a py file from inside a jupyter notebook, but I don't want to edit every time the name of the py file name changes. Is there a way to use $run with a variable filename? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any clue on what the new name is? Or perhaps you know for sure it's the only file in a certain directory? The problem is not very clear to me.

Comment: Yes, the name usually has the same format. I would like to search for the filename and $run the file that I find.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this and just in case anyone else does in the future I overcame it via this:

```
my_changing_string = 'testing_py_file'
exec(open("path_to_file/"+my_changing_string+".py").read())
```